# How to stop C# VLC player opening Direct3D Output window while playing the videos?

Tags: c#, .net, vlc, direct3d

I am trying to run the Videos (Live streaming from RTSP) using VLC from C# but sometime it's opening the new window VLC (Direct3D output) and not able to close the window too.
 Here is the sample code.

```
            m_players.Stop();
            IDiskPlayer player;
            player = m_factory.CreatePlayer<IDiskPlayer>();
            player.WindowHandle = p.Handle;
            m_players.Add(player);
            IMedia media = m_factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(videoURL);
            media.Events.StateChanged += Events_StateChanged;
            media.Tag = player.WindowHandle;
            player.Open(media);
            player.Play();
```

[image: Screenshot for video playing in separate window]